# How to get "gradle" have similar output details as "ant"?

Tags: gradle, ant, build.gradle, build.xml

<sub>My issue has no answer on questions [*How can I get Gradle ant logging to work?*](/q/27852451) and [*Gradle: Get Ant Task Output*](/q/28940473).</sub>

#### My ant script `build.xml`

```
<project>
  <target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="dest"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="dest" includeAntRuntime="false"/>
    <copy todir="dest" >
      <fileset dir="src" casesensitive="no">
        <include name="**/*.properties"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="MyJar.jar">
      <fileset dir="dest"/>
    </jar>
  </target>
</project>
```

#### The output of command `ant build` has some nice details

```
Buildfile: /some/path/build.xml

build:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /some/path/dest
    [javac] Compiling 25 source files to /some/path/dest
     [copy] Copying 3 files to /some/path/dest
      [jar] Building jar: /some/path/MyJar.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

#### Simple script `build.gradle`

```m
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

#### The output of command `gradle build` is missing some details

```
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.638 secs
```

We can notice the missing lines about the commands `mkdir`, `javac`, `copy` and `jar`.

#### Option `--info` is too much verbose

```
> gradle --info build
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/master/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/some/path/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'o']
Evaluating root project 'o' using build file '/some/path/build.gradle'.
Compiling build file '/some/path/build.gradle' using SubsetScriptTransformer.
Compiling build file '/some/path/build.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'build' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':build']
:build (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:build
Executing task ':build' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
[ant:mkdir] Created dir: /some/path/dest
[ant:javac] Compiling 25 source files to /some/path/dest
[ant:copy] Copying 3 files to /some/path/dest
[ant:jar] Building jar: /some/path/MyJar.jar
:build (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.646 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.947 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I share here my solution if this can help someone else.</sub>

It depends on the version of Gradle!

## Using Gradle 2.13

Elevate the log level of the task build (Ant target) in the script `build.gradle`:

```m
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
build.logging.level = LogLevel.INFO
```

#### Output of `gradle build` is now similar to `ant build`

```
:build
[ant:mkdir] Created dir: /some/path/dest
[ant:javac] Compiling 25 source files to /some/path/dest
[ant:copy] Copying 3 files to /some/path/dest
[ant:jar] Building jar: /some/path/MyJar.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.692 secs
```

## Using Gradle 3.2

Add `ant.lifecycleLogLevel = "INFO"` in the script `build.gradle`:

```m
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
ant.lifecycleLogLevel = "INFO"
```

#### Output of command `gradle build`

```
:build
[ant:mkdir] Created dir: /some/path/dest
[ant:javac] Compiling 25 source files to /some/path/dest
[ant:copy] Copying 3 files to /some/path/dest
[ant:jar] Building jar: /some/path/MyJar.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.531 secs
```